# Ajax post returning success but not hitting the break point in VS while debugging

Tags: jquery, .net, asp.net-core, razor-pages

im writting a .net core 3.1 project using razor pages and i have a form that has the input of type button on which i wrote an ajax post for the onclick event. When testing the button click the success function of the ajax request is being executed but my break point is not being hit in visual studio

my form

```
            @page
            @model IndexModel
            @{
                ViewData["Title"] = "Home page";
             }
    
            <div class="text-center">
        <form method="post">
            <div class="form-group row">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <label asp-for="Model.Name"></label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-9">
                    <input asp-for="Model.Name" id="Name" value="" class="form-control" />
                </div>
            </div>
    
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <input type="button" class="submit btn btn-primary" value="Submit" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>

@section scripts{
    <script src="~/js/test.js"></script>
}
```

my jquery

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".submit").on('click', function () {

        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('name', $('#Name').val());
        $.ajax({
            url: '/?handler=OnPostModelAsync',
            type: 'POST',
            async:true,
            contentType: 'application/json',
            //dataType: 'json',
            beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader("XSRF-TOKEN",
                    $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
            },
            data: JSON.stringify(formData),
            success: function () {
                alert("success");
            },
            failure: function () {
                alert("failure-");
            }

        })
    })
})
```

my server side code

```
        using AjaxPostRazorPages.Models;
        using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
        using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
        using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
       using System.Threading.Tasks;

        namespace AjaxPostRazorPages.Pages
        {
            public class IndexModel : PageModel
           {
        private readonly ILogger<IndexModel> _logger;

        public IndexModel(ILogger<IndexModel> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }


        public TestModel Model { get; set; }
        public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync()
        {
            return Page();
        }

        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostModelAsync([FromBody] TestModel model)
        {
            return Page();
        }
    }
}
```

what im i doing wrong, any help will be appreciated

Comment: And where is your breaking point?

Answer (score 1):

First, there is no good reason for posting JSON to Razor pages. If you want to work with JSON in your application, you should use API controllers. Just post the form contents instead.

Next,

> url: '/?handler=OnPostModelAsync'

should be

`url: '/?handler=Model'`

You don't include the `OnPost`, `OnGet` or `Async` parts of the handler method's name in the handler name: https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/handler-methods#named-handler-methods

Other things:

1. Remove the `HttpPost` attribute from the method. Methods are matched to verbs based on the verb being part of the method name in Razor Pages.
2. Remove the `ValidateAntiForgeryToken` attribute. They are validated by default in Razor Pages.
3. Use the `BindProperty` attribute on your `Model` property instead of adding another instance of it as handler method parameter.

Here's a revised PageModel:

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    [BindProperty]
    public TestModel Model { get; set; }
    public void OnGet()
    {
    }
    public IActionResult OnPostModelAsync()
    {
        return Page();
    }
}
```

And here's the revised jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".submit").on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            url: '/?handler=Model',
            type: 'POST',
            data: $(this).closest('form').serialize(),
            success: function () {
                alert("success");
            },
            failure: function () {
                alert("failure-");
            }

        })
    })
})
```